# Is it too late to add sulfur to my vegetable garden soil?

Tags: vegetables, soil-amendment, nutrients

My soil test from my local county extension office says:

> Your pH is 7.4 ... You should incorporate sulfur to a depth of 6" at a rate of ½ lb per 100 sq. feet at least 6 weeks before planting in the spring.

I'm about 2-3 weeks from the historical last freeze in my area (Wichita, KS, Zone 6A), and I'd rather not wait "at least 6 weeks" from now before transplanting anything.

So is it too late to add sulfur now?  Or should I take any special precautions when applying it now?

Comment: what are you planting?  Did you plant it before and were disappointed?  Are you a farmer or a homeowner?

Comment: I'm a homeowner, I have never grown anything here before. I'll be planting a wide variety of vegetables.

Comment: @Flimzy Of course it should be spelt with a "ph" - as I keep telling the locals here in the Colonies! :-)

Comment: You might consider acidifying with peat moss instead of sulfur. It has a pH of about 4.0, *and* it'll add organic matter to the soil.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are suggesting incorporating sulfur to lower the ph of the soil.  The sulfur will become sulfuric acid in the presence of water.  If the soil had a ph of over 8 or you were a commercial farmer this would be a viable solution but would have to be done yearly.

Your soil ph of 7.4 is not extremely alkaline. Although most vegetables prefer a ph of 5.5 to 6.5 these vegetables will do well in your soil:

- beets
- broccoli
- cabbage
- brussel sprouts
- legumes
- turnips

Refer to this [pdf](http://www.eutechinst.com/tips/ph/15_soil_ph.pdf) which has a detailed list of what likes what.  You will see that with your soil ph these vegetables will not do as well:

- lettuce
- carrots
- corn
- potato
- peanuts
- watermelon

Your best investment which would help your garden in many ways and moderate your soil ph would be to add organic matter.

To grow the vegetables that like a lower ph you could consider a raised bed with large quantities of composted manure mixed with top soil.  In my area they have a "triple mix" of composted manure, top soil and peat moss.  If you have six to eight inches of a soil high in organic matter and you top dress it every spring with more organic matter then you will not need to use sulfer.

Edit:  Yes, I am suggesting that  you would be better off with a raised bed of your favourite mix of compost and top soil and grow the ph sensitive vegetables there.  Skip the sulfur...

Comment: I am hoping to grow some lettuce, carrots, and potatoes at least.  Is your suggestion still to just add a "crap ton" (pun intended) of compost and forget about using sulfur?